# Register generic EntityFrameworkCore DbContext in ASP.Net Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to use generic DbContext in `ASP.Net Core 1.0` however I am getting following error:

```
ArgumentException: Type 'idmin.data.IdminDataContext`1[System.Int32]' does not have a default constructor Parameter name: type
```

Here is how IdminDataContext is defined:

```
public class IdminDataContext<TKey> : DbContext where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{

    public IdminDataContext(DbContextOptions<IdminDataContext<TKey>> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Idmin.Models.Client<TKey>> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I am registering it in startup class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = "my connection string";
    services.AddDbContext<IdminDataContext<int>>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I tried adding default constructor in IdminDataContext class but it didn't help.
Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found issue. It was silly mistake on my part. Instead of using constructor injection in Controller I was using action method injection which was causing exception in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder's CreateModel method. Fixed this issue by moving dependency injection to constructor instead of action method injection.

Comment: I had the same issue. I had my interface injected into the controller action (Index). Now I added a constructor to my controller and injected the interface there and it works. But I don't quite understand what was wrong with the action method injection.